# Irrlicht: draw 2D image in 3D space based on four corner coordinates

Tags: c++, 3d, irrlicht

I would like to create a function to position a free-floating 2D raster image in space with the Irrlicht engine. The inspiration for this is the function [rgl::show2d](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgl/versions/0.97.0/topics/show2d) in the R package rgl. An example implementation in R can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41977727/3216883).

[image: chewie in space]

The input data should be limited to the path to the image and a table with the four corner coordinates of the respective plot rectangle.

My first, pretty primitive and finally unsuccessful approach to realize this with irrlicht:

Create a cube:

```
ISceneNode * picturenode = scenemgr->addCubeSceneNode();
```

Flatten one side:

```
picturenode->setScale(vector3df(1, 0.001, 1));
```

Add image as texture:

```
picturenode->setMaterialTexture(0, driver->getTexture("path/to/image.png"));
```

Place flattened cube at the center position of the four corner coordinates. I just calculate the mean coordinates on all three axes with a small function `position_calc()`.

```
vector3df position = position_calc(rcdf); picturenode->setPosition(position);
```

Determine the object rotation by calculating the normal of the plane defined by the four corner coordinates, normalizing the result and trying to somehow translate the resulting vector to rotation angles.

```
vector3df normal = normal_calc(rcdf);
vector3df angles = (normal.normalize()).getSphericalCoordinateAngles();
picturenode->setRotation(angles);
```

This solution doesn't produce the expected result. The rotation calculation is wrong. With this approach I'm also not able to scale the image correctly to it's corner coordinates.

How can I fix my workflow? Or is there a much better way to achieve this with Irrlicht that I'm not aware of?

---

**Edit:** Thanks to @spug I believe I'm almost there. I tried to implement his method 2, because [quaternions](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1core_1_1quaternion.html) are already available in Irrlicht. Here's what I came up with to calculate the rotation:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <irrlicht.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

core::vector3df rotation_calc(DataFrame rcdf) {

  NumericVector x = rcdf["x"];
  NumericVector y = rcdf["y"];
  NumericVector z = rcdf["z"];

  // Z-axis
  core::vector3df zaxis(0, 0, 1);
  // resulting image's normal
  core::vector3df normal = normal_calc(rcdf);

  // calculate the rotation from the original image's normal (i.e. the Z-axis) 
  // to the resulting image's normal => quaternion P.
  core::quaternion p;
  p.rotationFromTo(zaxis, normal);

  // take the midpoint of AB from the diagram in method 1, and rotate it with 
  // the quaternion P => vector U.
  core::vector3df MAB(0, 0.5, 0);
  core::quaternion m(MAB.X, MAB.Y, MAB.Z, 0);
  core::quaternion rot = p * m * p.makeInverse();
  core::vector3df u(rot.X, rot.Y, rot.Z);

  // calculate the rotation from U to the midpoint of DE => quaternion Q
  core::vector3df MDE(
      (x(0) + x(1)) / 2,
      (y(0) + y(1)) / 2,
      (z(0) + z(1)) / 2
  );
  core::quaternion q;
  q.rotationFromTo(u, MDE);

  // multiply in the order Q * P, and convert to Euler angles
  core::quaternion f = q * p;
  core::vector3df euler;
  f.toEuler(euler);

  // to degrees
  core::vector3df degrees(
    euler.X * (180.0 / M_PI),
    euler.Y * (180.0 / M_PI),
    euler.Z * (180.0 / M_PI)
  );

  Rcout << "degrees: " <<  degrees.X << ", " << degrees.Y << ", " << degrees.Z << std::endl;

  return degrees;
}
```

The result is **almost** correct, but the rotation on one axis is wrong. Is there a way to fix this or is my implementation inherently flawed?

That's what the result looks like now. The points mark the expected corner points.

[image: berries in space]

Comment: what is `rcdf`?

Comment: I'm using the [Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) framework. It's a DataFrame object that represents - in this case - a table with 3 columns and 4 rows. The x, y and z coordinates of the four corner points. Sorry - I forgot to describe this.

Comment: The problem with this is there are only *two* spherical coordinate angles; you need a third to specify the rotation of the image around the `normal` - this is called the roll. Are you at least able to get the image *plane* to point in the correct direction?

Comment: You mean if the my function to calculate the normal is correct? I implemented  [this](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/172697-Surface-Normal-Function-Not-really-sure?p=1210601&viewfull=1#post1210601) example.

Comment: I assumed you know how to implement it (quite simple) - just wanted to check before we can move on. My point is that the normal itself does not contain information about the rotation of the image *around* it. This is a mathematical idea, not a mistake in your normal calculation.

Comment: I start to understand this now. I was not familiar with the difference between yaw, pitch and roll. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782647/how-to-get-yaw-pitch-and-roll-from-a-3d-vector) what I'm searching for?

Comment: Not quite. 1) you can't obtain yaw from `normal`, 2) yaw and pitch are slightly differently defined compared to spherical polars.

Comment: So... Where does that leave me? Obviously it's possible to project a 2D image in 3D space with this kind of position information. How?

Comment: When the rotation is zero, what are the coordinates of the image? Are they in the x-y plane?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused at this point... but I'm pretty sure, that the default rotation setup (0,0,0) causes the image to lie flat on the x-y plane.

Comment: I'll come back to you in a few hours. This may take some work to do.

Comment: @spug Still interested in the topic?

Comment: sorry, I've been thinking about it for a few days, and Irrlicht's restriction to Euler angles is quite annoying; Euler angles are definitely not the way to go for a reverse-calculation problem like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought of two ways to do this; neither are very graceful - not helped by Irrlicht restricting us to spherical polars.

NB. the below assumes `rcdf` is centered at the origin; this is to make the rotation calculation a bit more straightforward. Easy to fix though:

1. Compute the center point (the translational offset) of `rcdf`
2. Subtract this from all the points of `rcdf`
3. Perform the procedures below
4. Add the offset back to the result points.

---

*Pre-requisite: scaling*

This is easy; simply calculate the ratios of width and height in your `rcdf` to your original image, then call `setScaling`.

[image]

---

*Method 1: matrix inversion*

For this we need an external library which supports 3x3 matrices, since Irrlicht only has 4x4 (I believe).

We need to solve the matrix equation which rotates the image from X-Y to `rcdf`. For this we need *3 points* in each frame of reference. Two of these we can immediately set to *adjacent* corners of the image; the third must point out of the plane of the image (since we need data in all three dimensions to form a complete basis) - so to calculate it, simply multiply the normal of each image by some offset constant (say 1).

[image]

(Note the points on the original image have been scaled)

The equation to solve is therefore:

[image]

(Using column notation). The `Eigen` library offers an implementation for 3x3 matrices and inverse.

Then convert this matrix to spherical polar angles: https://www.learnopencv.com/rotation-matrix-to-euler-angles/

---

Method 2:

To calculate the *quaternion* to rotate from direction vector A to B: [Finding quaternion representing the rotation from one vector to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171849/finding-quaternion-representing-the-rotation-from-one-vector-to-another)

1. Calculate the rotation from the original image's *normal* (i.e. the Z-axis) to `rcdf`'s normal => quaternion `P`.
2. Take the *midpoint* of **AB** from the diagram in method 1, and rotate it with the quaternion `P` (http://www.geeks3d.com/20141201/how-to-rotate-a-vertex-by-a-quaternion-in-glsl/) => vector `U`.
3. Calculate the rotation from `U` to the midpoint of **DE** => quaternion `Q`
4. Multiply in the order `Q * P`, and convert to Euler angles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

(Not sure if Irrlicht has support for quaternions)

Comment: Ok I tried to implement method 2. What you mind taking a look at it There's unfortunately an error in my approach.

Comment: @nevrome hi sorry for the delay; why are there 6 points in the diagram? and I assume the lower polygon is the end result?

Comment: @nevrome ah I just realized - the answer assumes that `rcdf` is centered at the origin, but I see your `rcdf` has a translational offset; this is pretty easy to fix however - just compute the center beforehand, subtract it from `rcdf`'s points, do the computation, and add it back on. I think this might be causing the incorrect angle, because the *normal* calculation is not affected by this translation, so the final plane would be correct but not the in-plane orientation.

Comment: Oh - no sorry, that's confusing. I plotted to different pictures, to check the result by looking at their relationship. The second picture is a point of reference for the other to check the algorithm.

Comment: @nevrome I've updated the answer with the (potential) solution; can you try it and see if it works

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve it yet. I think the position of the midpoint between A and B (MAB) is the problem. How do I get MAB? I thought it should be the same for every image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149322/discussion-between-nevrome-and-spug).

Comment: @nevrome that depends on how your `DataFrame rcdf` is set up. It looks like a customizable data structure and I don't know what the internal data layout is. The purpose of getting the midpoint MAB is to reduce the effect of any numerical inaccuracy in the scaling operation. MAB in the example is just (0, scaled_height/2, 0).

Comment: @nevrome good news - I got this to work! I simply changed the order of multiplication from `core::quaternion f = q * p` to `p * q`; no idea why this worked, maybe because Irrlicht's convention for multiplication order is different ..(?)

Comment: @nevrome I did yes; however I used a different implementation to rotate points with the quaternion - uk.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/quaternionrotation.html ; somehow this worked and not the qvq* method

Comment: I'm not at home this week unfortunately. Would you mind preparing a pull request with this code chunk for the rotation?

Comment: @nevrome sorry, I don't use github / Irrlicht so I don't know how to do that. But I can put my C code on pastebin for you (I implemented everything from scratch)

Comment: I would love that!

Comment: @nevrome ok here you go: https://pastebin.com/Xy33ZywS . Excuse my absolutely atrocious code style, but I wanted to condense the duplicate boilerplate code as much as possible. Note the implementation of `q_rot` as it is the different rotation method I used.

Comment: Thanks! Works now - Wohoo! I wonder what would be the best way to clean up this messy question.

Comment: @nevrome why bother? Leave it as it is, so that future generations can learn from our utter disorganization -_-